# Build Error in VS 2010 Basic express when opened via UNC path

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

When any vb.net solution file is opened **via Long UNC path** & when trying to build it, I am getting below attached errors.

```
Unable to write to output file '\\pc2\G\xxxx\xxxx\obj\Release\xxxx.exe': Access is denied.
```

Works fine while opened with local non-UNC path. ex  G:\xxxx\xxxx

> Microsoft Visual Basic 2010 Express

Errors occurs only in some of systems.
We have checked by adding/removing permission attributes & also checked by giving Full control Users permission to specific folder path, we have already tried this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2010/85s7w197(v=vs.100)?redirectedfrom=MSDN).

Comment: Could it be that some other computer, or maybe anti-virus software, has that file open?

Comment: @AndrewMorton We have checked by disabling AV & no one has that file open.

Comment: Have you used [Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) to see if there is a difference in the entries for that file between a working and non-working machine?

Comment: @AndrewMorton what type of entries need to be checked? or do you mean process explorer?

Comment: I'd look to see if there is any difference at all (other than the Access Denied) in the Operation and Path columns. Oh, just thought, does "Build" -> "Clean Solution" delete the xxxx.exe file?

Comment: @AndrewMorton I have tried above solution, but that's not working for me

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Here's how I solved it:

1. Under Build menu, I used "Clean Solution" and then "Clean *your project name*" and then rebuilt them in the same order.

2. Build solution again, then build *your project name* again.

3. run debug

Seems like VS is locking files while debuging but when debuging ends it won't unlock the files. Try this. Won't hurt.